# Is there a viable melee Demon Hunter build for Inferno?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

Is there a viable Demon Hunter build with melee weapons that I can still use in Inferno? I need a new challenge for my third character :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am currently playing a melee/grenadier demonhunter in Inferno act 3 and it's working so far.

### My [skillset](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/demon-hunter#UeXVTS!baV!cccYbb) choices:

- **[Grenades](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/grenades)** runed with (gas grenades) can be used without a bow or crossbow as well as any melee weapon and have a higher damage output
  than autoattacks.
- **[Chakram](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/chakram)** runed with (shuriken cloud) is used as area of effect damage
  in melee range. It's very hatred efficient and does decent damage as
  long as you are not beeing attacked.
- **[Smokescreen](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/smoke-screen)** with (choking gas) runed works offensive and defensive.
  It's your best escape tool while adding additional damage.
- **[Preperation](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/preparation)** and (focused mind) rune give you the necessary resources
  to continue dishing out in long fights and keep spamming abilites.
- As **[Companion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/companion)** I chose the (boar companion) rune because of the area of
  effect damage and it's sustain. Decent damage and it looks awesome ;)
- Last but not least, **[Spiketrap](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/spike-trap)** as your main source of damage. The
  (long fuse) rune is the best option in my opinion because 371% weapon
  damage is so much damage and works especially great when spammed and
  in big packs. Even boss's hp drop very quickly when using this skill

### **My passives:**

- **[Vengeance](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/passive/vengeance)** gives you additional hatred to spam bombs as well as giving
  you more sustain when picking up health globes. I haven't used it in
  the lower difficulties but you will need it in inferno.
- **[Tactical Advantage](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/passive/tactical-advantage)** is my get out of jail free card. I ran into the
  problem of not beeing able to escape in time after using smoke
  screen. This passive solves it and helps you to spread the choking
  gas rune's effect.
- **[Numbing traps](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/passive/numbing-traps)** are a must-have for every melee build involving traps.
  You can try other passives but especially in inferno this is the best
  way to keep you alive!

### Playstyle

The best thing about this build is it's easy execution. Just run up to the mobs with active Chakram and spam the ground under you with spike traps. You boar will do additional damage while you keep doing damage with grenades the moment your hatred runs out.

You can use preperation inbetween attacks to spam additional traps and get out when you feel you can't survive or want to reposition by using smoke screen.

### **Nightmare and beyond**

In harder difficulties your main problem will be the damage output of the enemys. Try to lure them into your traps and use smoke screen for escapes. If you can divide the enemies into smaller packs you will be able to kill them very quickly.

### **Item priorities**

Your weapon can be everything with good stats/dmg. If you want to autoattack try a fast sword but grenades are just better in comparison.

Try to aim for a mix of dexterity and vitality. Vitality should be your first priority while maxing dex for "enough" damage output. Equip with damage on hit is always nice but don't use it when the stats are otherwise crappy. It's just a bonus and you don't need it as much as you need to stay alive.

I've had a lot of fun playing this build and still enjoy it. Keep me posted and ask if you have further questions about the specific skills or the build in general.

Comment: Did you mean to say: Chakram runed with (shuriken cloud) is used as area of effect damage in melee range. It's very hatred efficient and does decent damage as long as you are **not** being attacked.